# OpenCV Cannot find MatND_

Tags: c++, opencv

I was trying to update OpenCV (to 2.4.9) when I ran into a problem. I cannot find the file that defines "MatND_". In the old version of OpenCV it was in cxcore.cpp. I searched through google, the CV documentation and the new OpenCV library and found a lot of information regarding MatND but nothing relevant about MatND_.  Does anyone know where I can find it?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: try grep'ing for it: `grep -R 'MatND_' .`

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am developing on windows so no grep.  I have already tried searching through the contents of the new library (searched for "content:MatND_")

Comment: No grep on windows? Not true: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=windows+grep

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OpenCV was "*the old version*". Even in 2.2 cxcore.hpp had comments about being deprecated and did not have `MatND_`. ?

If `MatND_` is to `MatND` as `Mat_` is to `Mat, you may be able to just use a`Mat_`

`MatND` is declared in opencv2/core/core.hpp:

```
typedef Mat MatND;
```